# How to use google reverse Geocoding in react js typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web

I have implement reverse Geocoding in my useEffect,
but I got some error for unknown reason.
I need to convert lat and lng in formattedAdress.

```
  const geocoder = new window.google.maps.Geocoder();
  const latlng = {
    lat: value.coordinates.latitude,
    lng: value.coordinates.longitude,
  };
```

[image: here is useEffect hook that give geocode and reversed geocode]

[I have got this error twice, I added in line 75 geocoder and latlng:][2]

The above error occurred in the  component:

caught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'maps')

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [don't post images of your error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), paste them into your question instead.

It looks like the Google Maps API hasn't been loaded on your page. So when the browser tries to read `window.google.maps`, it finds that `window.google` is `undefined` and throws an error when it tries to read the `maps` property.

Comment: You need to have the Google Maps JavaScript API running on your page before you can use it. I recommend you start with [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api)